# gRPC cleanUp() callback for a server in golang?

Tags: go, interceptor, grpc-go

I want to do some clean ups just after the gRPC server will stop, e.g.:

```
func cleanUp(...) (...) {
  // do something
}

func main() {
  ...
  sOpts := []grpc.ServerOptions{ /* some opts */ }
  sOpts = append(sOpts, grpc.UnaryInterceptor(unaryInterceptor))
  sOpts = append(sOpts, grpc.CleanUpInterceptor(cleanUp))
  s := grpc.NewServer(sOpts...)
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you legitimately want to use request interceptors here? Because that doesn't really match your description of "clean ups just after the gRPC server will stop". What are you looking to clean up?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one `os.Signal` to get the gRPC server shutdown signal, monitor this signal in the `cleanup` interceptor then do clean-up jobs when this signal is triggered.

Sample codes

```golang
    sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1) 

    cleanUp := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{},
        info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
        handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {

        select {
        case <-sigCh:
            // do some server shutdown logic
        default:
        }
        h, err := handler(ctx, req)

        return h, err
    }

    sOpts := []grpc.ServerOptions{ /* some opts */ }
    sOpts = append(sOpts, grpc.UnaryInterceptor(unaryInterceptor))
    sOpts = append(sOpts, grpc.UnaryInterceptor(cleanUp))

    signal.Notify(sigCh, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM) // more signal could be added
    s := grpc.NewServer(sOpts...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    defer func() {
       s.Stop()
       doSomething()
    }
```

There is no way to get a signal from gRPC Servers consistently on whether they have stopped.